# Ordinal 343 not found Win32 VC++ exports

Tags: api, winapi, visual-c++

I'm writing Windows CE API compatibility wrapper for Win32. It just wraps coredll.dll calls into Win32 ones. So, I made coredll project in Visual Studio, then I did a lot of exports in .def file like here:

```
    WaitForSingleObject @497
    WaitForMultipleObjects @498
    SuspendThread @499
    ResumeThread @500
    SetThreadContext @502
    ReadProcessMemory @506
    WriteProcessMemory @507
```

All Windows CE programs are using ordinal to call function, so I defined appropriate ordinal in .def file for each function. See the full source code here: https://github.com/feel-the-dz3n/WinCeCompatLayer

But when I try to link this library and call function from it, Windows says that ordinal 343 not found in COREDLL.DLL.

[image: Error screenshot]

Error appears even if 343 is defined, so it seems like the problem is in using VC++ or in exports.

P.S.: My library currently uses Windows 10 functions, so it may throw some errors on another versions of Windows

`dumpbin coredll.dll /exports` - [output](https://pastebin.com/1qiCr5zJ)

Comment: Try `dumpbin /exports` to see what's actually being exported in your DLL.

Comment: @JonathanPotter [Output of dumpbin](https://pastebin.com/1qiCr5zJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, but the reason was line from exports.def below:

```
DSA_Clone     @1853
```

It's related to WinAPI, so I don't really know the reason.